# Artifactory REST API rejects valid JSON

Tags: java, rest, artifactory

I am passing the following call to the Artifactory REST API which is resulting in `"Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): expected a valid value`

However, this JSON is dead simple and valid:

```
{
    "exportPath": "Invalid"
}
```

The curl looks like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d export-settings.json -X POST https://artifactory.i.build.mgp.ninja/artifactory/api/export/system`

I also tried using `application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.system.ExportSettings+json` as the `Content-Type` header which gave me a 400 (I saw this pattern in other places, though it is foreign to me).

What could be causing this? The [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ExportSystem) don't go into much depth.

Note: I first hit errors writing a Golang wrapper for this API, where I got 415's.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way th curl is being sent is incorrect, when using -d option and passing the JSON file, '@' should be used. So the below curl command should be helpful,

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d @export-settings.json -X POST https://artifactory.i.build.mgp.ninja/artifactory/api/export/system

Or use the below curl command to test if the JSON is being taken as a valid or not,

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d '{"exportPath":"Invalid"}' -X POST https://artifactory.i.build.mgp.ninja/artifactory/api/export/system